# Приложение на c# для проверки пакетов

Tags: c#, шифрование

Нужно приложение для отправки, приёма и проверки на подленность пакетов. Содержимое пакетов роли не играет. Главная задача-механизм проверки подлинности + что бы была реализована защита от перехвата и подмены. Буду рад любым подсказкам, спасибо!

Comment: Ну, например, цифровая подпись?

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, она не особо подходит. Мне нужно создать средство для проведения безопасных транзакций, но не особо углублённое. То есть практическое применение стоит далеко не на первом месте. Если есть какие-то решения буду благодарен(желательно кодом). Спасибо!

Comment: Ничего не понял. Чем вам цифровая подпись не подходит?

Comment: [Электро́нная по́дпись (ЭП), Электро́нная цифровая по́дпись (ЭЦП), Цифровая подпись (ЦП) позволяет подтвердить авторство электронного документа (будь то реальное лицо или, например, аккаунт в криптовалютной системе). Подпись связана как с автором, так и с самим документом с помощью криптографических методов, и не может быть подделана с помощью обычного копирования.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)

Comment: Чем https вам не угодил? И то, и другое в наличии, бери и используй.

Comment: Пересылайте Hash

Comment: Думаю, в этих двух пространствах имён: [System.Net.Security](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security), [System.Security.Cryptography](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography) - есть всё вам необходимое.